# Is there a word that means "both micro and macro"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, mathematics

I am looking for a word that means "micro and macro". For instance, if I was describing an economic phenomenon that can be observed on both the micro and macro levels of the economy, I could call it a **__** phenomenon.

If you don't know of a "real" English term for this, I'm open to suggestions for new words!

Comment: I think suggestions for new words fall outside the scope of this site, but how about poly- or omni- (depending on whether you want "many" or "all") -scopic or -scalar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to invent new words right yet, we have terms for many of these things!

One of the most commonly recognized scale-independent forms is the **Fractal**. It mains the same form whether 'big' or 'small'.

In fact, the concepts 'big' or 'small' don't even have a real connection to fractals, which gets at the essence of what you're thinking.

---

Generally, you are referring to ***scale-independent*** or ***scale-invariant*** phenomena.

You could use the word *scaleless*, but I find its awkward to many people.

---

Source: I have published an article about scale-invariance.

Answer (score 5):

I think what fits best in this particular case is:

> "I could call it a *universal* phenomenon."

Comment: In general use, his means that it *occurs* everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

> - broadscale
> - wide-spectrum
> - full spectrum
> - full range

Answer (score 1):

How about: "A general phenomenon" ? Is it too generic ?

Answer (score 1):

One way of answering this would be to suggest words meaning "present everywhere", such as [ubiquitous](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ubiquitous?q=ubiquitous):

> present, appearing, or found everywhere

- and its synonyms.

A different approach would be to consider words that mean "displaying the same characteristics at all ranges of scales" - this is less commonplace, but the mathematical term [fractal](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fractal?q=fractal) springs to mind:

> a curve or geometrical figure, each part of which has the same statistical character as the whole.